# error: keepererrorcode = connectionloss for /hbase - Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0

Tags: apache, hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-zeppelin

Facing issue "error: keepererrorcode = connectionloss for /hbase" while running hbase jobs in Zeppelin. Hbase version - 1.2 , Apache Zeppelin 0.8.0 compiled with HBase 1.2.

Hbase running in CDH 5.11.0 Cluster

Hbase commands run successfully from CLI from same host but fails from Zeppelin UI. Zeppelin hosts is configured as Edge node to the CDH cluster.

Spark jobs run without any issues.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Regards,
Shrilesh

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to draw a conclusion. But my guess is you are probably using the default Spark comes with Zeppelin. The embedded spark in Zeppelin is only meant for development. It can't do heavy lifting. Try set it up with "yarn-client" master. Another thing I've learned is not everything written in a normal Scala project can run smoothly in Zeppelin.

I've documented my work at http://www.antsdb.com/?p=121 for you reference